# Nginx returning error 404 when redirect to docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a simple application with two separated containers: one to the backend (api-container) and other to the frontend (front-container).

I`d like to configure ngnix to redirect all requests from domain api.myurl.com to backend container and all requests from myurl.com to the frontend container.

To do that I configured the ngnix, as showed below:

```
server {

    listen  80;
    server_name myurl.com;

    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        proxy_pass http://front-container:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name api.myurl.com;
    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        proxy_pass http://api-container:3010;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Everything works almost fine. When I access http://myurl.com everything is ok but when access another route like http://myurl.com/other the ngnix returns 404 error. This route works like a charm without ngnix.

What is wrong in my configuration?

Important: ngninx is running also in a container in the same network to other containers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with config nginx. Pls, check the block **location** and change follow below code:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```